# What phones, regions, builds can use voice activation ("Hey Cortana")?

Tags: speech

On my Lumia 930 with Windows 10 Mobile (no Insider Build) there's an option for "Hey Cortana" in Settings -> Extras. Unfortunately it tells me that this feature is not available for my language and region.

So my questions are:

- What languages and regions are supported?
- What version of Windows 10 Mobile to I need?
- Is this a hardware-related feature?

Comment: It is definetly  hardware related feature. The passive voice activation technology used in "Hey Cortana" does not work on all hardwares. That is the reason told to me why my phone is not having that feature.

Comment: seems like it has to be a Snapdragon 800 or higher processor
http://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-hey-cortana-windows-10-mobile

Comment: so, It cant be possible on my 520?

Comment: Try USA region, then it's should be work